# How to use iMacros File Access Module on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, imacros

I'm able to use iMacros for Chrome and read from a .csv file perfectly fine on Windows 8.

But the exact same script/setup no longer works when using Windows 10.

Any ideas how I can make it work?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your script in order to increase your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out windows 10 was not the culprit at all. iMacros works exactly the same on both windows 8 and 10 as far as i can tell.

The issue is that the .CSV file i was reading from somehow had a huge ammount of empty cells (and hence loads of commas), which made the file too big to be read.

I deleted the rogue commas, and now all is well.